# Connecting Raspberry Pi to laptop

Tags: pi-3

So I got a raspberry pi 3 as a gift and my only spare monitor and keyboard is my laptop, a cheap lenovo ideapad. The laptop is thin and light, so it lacks an Ethernet cable which means I can't follow any of the tutorials on how to connect it by that. The laptop has an hdmi, 2 usbs headphone jack, microsd and that is it, anyone know how to use the keyboard and screen from a laptop for a pi without ethernet?

Comment: Do you have a router?

Comment: USB on the laptop?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a way to setup a headless Raspberry Pi without ever needing to connect it to a monitor, keyboard and mouse.

This easiest way I have found to do this is by [using PiBakery](http://pibakery.org/) to image your Pi's SD Card, since you can specify your WiFi login details and enable the VNC server all from your laptop.

So basically, [install and use PiBakery](http://pibakery.org/) to image the SD Card providing your WiFi details and enabling VNC, then insert the SD Card in the Pi and connect it to power.

Then [install VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) on your laptop, open it and go to 'raspberry.local', enter 'pi' as username and 'raspberry' for the password, and you are in.

Finally, go to Preferences, Raspberry Pi Configuration, and Set Resolution to DMT mode 85 1280x720 for example, and restart your Pi, so you'll get a bigger resolution via VNC on your headless Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Get this cable:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/954
You Can connect this cable to Raspberry Pi and can have direct terminal access.
[image]

Its very easy. 
Then configure WiFi on RPI and install program called VNC server on Raspberry Pi.
Using VNC you can access User Interface of RPI directly on your chrome browser in Laptop. You will need Chrome extension for VNC Client.